# How to set the colour of an alpha blended GL_TEXTURE_2D in a QGLWidget

Tags: qt, opengl

I'm a newbie with blending and textures in Opengl.  My render_text() method uses the drawText method in QPainter with a QImage as its device.  The QImage becomes a GL_TEXTURE_2D and then is attached to a GL_QUADS.  The text appears correctly over the 2d scene as black.  I would like to know how to arbitrarily set the colour.  If anyone can recommend a good tutorial on how the source to destination blending works would also benefit.

```
void GLView::render_text(char *txt, quint8 height)
{
    QImage image;
    qint32 font_height, width;

    font_height = height * VIEW_SIZE / (ZOOM * OBJ_HEIGHT);

    QFont font("Helvetica", font_height);
    QFontMetrics fm(font);

    // render text in QImage
    QImage img(fm.width(txt), fm.height(), QImage::Format_ARGB32);
    img.fill(0);
    QPainter pixPaint(&img);
    pixPaint.setFont(font);
    pixPaint.drawText(0, font_height, txt);

    // push to gl
    image = QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(img);

    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);

    //glBlendColor(1, 0, 0, 0.5);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, image.width(), image.height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL );

    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, image.width(), image.height(), GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image.bits() );

    width = image.width() * ZOOM * OBJ_WIDTH / VIEW_SIZE;       //calc object width from image width

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2i(0,0); glVertex2f(0, 0);
    glTexCoord2i(0,1); glVertex2f(0, height);
    glTexCoord2i(1,1); glVertex2f(width, height);
    glTexCoord2i(1,0); glVertex2f(width, 0);
    glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glDeleteTextures(1, &texture);
}
```

Comment: Well, obviously you can paint in the right color in the first place -- set the color on the QPainter object! And may I suggest you use QGLFrameBufferObject? You can draw into it with the QPainter and then draw it as texture with a Qt call within your GL code. Advantages: 1. Qt will use OpenGL for rendering the text, 2. No copy to the GPU needed. Verdict: Much faster!

Comment: Yep, setting the colour with QPen works.  I had tried using a QPen before without success, must have had something else wrong.  I'll give QGLFrameBufferObject a try tomorrow.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can paint in the right color in the first place -- set the color on the `QPainter` object / `QPen`!
2. May I suggest you use `QGLFrameBufferObject`? You can draw into it with the `QPainter` and then draw it as texture with a Qt call within your GL code. Advantages:

   - Qt will use OpenGL for rendering the text
   - No copy to the GPU needed.
   - => Much faster!

Comment: I had to pen.setColor(QColor(255,255,255,255)); and then I could use glColor3ub() to set the colour to what ever I want.  Still trying to figure out painting to QGLFrameBufferObject.

Comment: `QGLFramebufferObject fbo(fm.width(txt), fm.height(), QGLFramebufferObject::CombinedDepthStencil);
QPainter pixPaint(&fbo);`
gives "QGLShader: could not create shader"

Comment: Make sure you have GL context when creating the FBO and painting to it. That means you need to create it only after the context was created and then also make sure that you have the context. I use QGLWidget to draw GL stuff and create my FBOs within the widget. With QGLWidget::makeCurrent(); I enforce the GL context. Within QGLWidget::paintEvent() you always have GL context.

Comment: The render_text method is called between a glNewList and glEndList.  The list is called in GLView::paintGL().  I no longer get the "could not create shaderMoving" by moving the call to render_text into the GLView::paintGL().  The problem is I'm scrolling the GL viewing area with a translate in GLView::paintGL() and I don't want redraw text until I zoom.

Comment: First of all, you can create the FBO anytime (within context) and keep it and draw in it whenever you want. So you don't need to prepare it at the same position you draw it. Second, probably it is a GL violation to do this stuff within the display list creation. FBOs are outside the scope of a display list. Third, display lists are deprecated by vertex arrays / vertex buffer objects (QGLBuffer). But you can still use them. Just sayin'.

Comment: Recommend any books or tutorials on learning VBOs?  After the last 30min reading about them, I'd rather program in assembler!

Comment: Oh, they are actually super-easy. It just looks complicated. Have a look at http://sourceforge.net/p/gerbil/svn/HEAD/tree/branches/next/gui/dist_view/compute.cpp starting at line 91. There a QGLBuffer object is initialized and then a float array is mapped into memory to be filled with data. In http://sourceforge.net/p/gerbil/svn/HEAD/tree/branches/next/gui/dist_view/viewport_drawing.cpp starting at line 209 you can see how the vector is then used for drawing lines. I used the GL extension's documentation and tutorials (google). http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/vertex_buffer_object.txt